# Why are these 2 cout statements giving opposite result?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I can't understand why the statements are giving different results as According to Me
**a==b** is same as **b==a**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
   cout<<(pow(10,2)==(pow(8,2)+pow(6,2)))<<endl;
   cout<<((pow(8,2)+pow(6,2))==pow(10,2))<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT IS**-

```
1
0
```

Comment: Floating precision...

Comment: comparing floats with `==` is always a bad idea

Comment: do not use `pow` for integer types!

Comment: Cannot [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5GKoTcPTz), BTW. What compiler/version/standard are you using?

Comment: anyway I wonder which compiler gives this result. Outcome should be same even for floating point lack of precision. Gcc gives `1` twice: https://godbolt.org/z/T6j3dz7aK

Comment: An implementation of `pow` that doesn't return the best possible `double` for integral arguments ought to be considered defective. Of course neither the C++ nor IEEE754 mandates that (cf. `sqrt` where IEEE754 does). A good toolchain ought to give you the result you expect. You might get better results with `std::pow` which has overloads for integral types.

Comment: I can recreate the behaviour with gcc-6.3.0 that ships with mingw32

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the output you get from this [snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/1o8c41YKh)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is double comparison issue. You can use something like:

```
   cout<<(fabs(pow(10,2) - (pow(8,2)+pow(6,2))) <  std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() ) <<endl;
   cout<<(fabs((pow(8,2)+pow(6,2))-pow(10,2)) <  std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() ) <<endl;
```

Ref:
[What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)